# Xcode clang link: Build Dynamic Framework (or dylib) not embed dependencies

Tags: xcode, hyperlink, clang, ld, dylib

I’m building a dynamic framework for iOS. It needs reference some symbols from code or other libraries, but I not want link them into the framework.

This can be achieved when build an static library, just setup search path and make sure them not included in target’s build phases.

But when build a dynamic framework or dylib, this result undefined symbol error. I tried all kinds of link options, eg `-l` `-weak_library` `-weak_framework` `-I` `-rpath` `-rpath-link`. But none works.

The link command looks like this:

```
clang -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib
    -isysroot *iPhone_SDK_PATH* 
    *OPTIONS_NOT_IMPORTANT* 
    -install_name @rpath/Foo.framework/Foo
    -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks
    -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks
    -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker *BUILD_PATH*
    -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0
    -Xlinker -no_deduplicate
    -Xlinker -objc_abi_version
    -Xlinker 2 
    -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime
    -framework Foundation
    -single_module
    -compatibility_version 1
    -current_version 1
    -Xlinker -dependency_info
    -Xlinker *BUILD_PATH*/Foo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Foo_dependency_info.dat 
    -o *BUILD_PATH*/Foo.framework/Foo
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

clang use ld command to make the final link, I checked the manual and found `-U` and `-undefined` can ignore undefined symbols.

> -U symbol_name
>
> > Specified that it is ok for symbol_name to have no definition.  With two_levelnamespace, the resulting symbol will be marked dynamic_lookup which means dyld will search all loaded images.
>
> -undefined treatment
>
> > Specifies how undefined symbols are to be treated. Options are: error, warning, suppress, or dynamic_lookup.  The default is error.

So the final solution is set `-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup` to `OTHER_LDFLAGS`, also make sure search path set correctly. It works.

Comment: Setting `-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup` to `OTHER_LDFLAGS ` works, but it disable all warnings. Is there a way to just suppress warning for one symbol? Using the option `-U` should do it, but setting for example `-U _mysymbol` to `OTHER_LDFLAGS` doesn't work.

Comment: I am using this syntax `-Wl,-U,symbol_name`